# How to apply "sequence of tenses" to "would like"

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

This is a sentence in direct speech:

> They asked me: "Which of these books would you like to take".

I need to rewrite it in indirect speech. And obviously I have to apply *sequence of tenses* rule.

My idea is:

> They asked me which of these books I wanted to take.

Is it correct? And maybe it's possible to keep "would like" somehow:

> They asked me which of these books I would like to take.

But it seems to violate *sequence of tenses*. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In everyday conversation many would use one or other of the two you quote. Though to be strictly correct I suppose it should be -

***They asked me which of these books I would have liked to have taken***.